# Не выводит значение из трех таблиц Django

Tags: python, html, django

`views.py`:

```py
def viewUser(request):
    """Вывод просмотренных птиц пользователям."""
    login = request.POST.get("login")  # FIXME Не стоит передавать значение от пользователя всырой SQL-запрос.
    sql_get = """SELECT Birds.name, Birds.PNG, Birds.feather_color, ViewedUser.DataTime
                                  FROM User, Birds, ViewedBirds
                                  WHERE User.login = %s
                                  AND Birds.id_birds = ViewedBirds.id_birds
                                  AND User.id_user = ViewedBirds.id_user
                                  GROUP BY ViewedBirds.DataTime;""" % login
    view = ViewedUser.objects.raw(sql_get)  # FIXME может привести к SQL-инъекциям.
    return render(request, 'viewUser.html/', {'view': view}, {'login': login})
```

Шаблон:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="viewUser"> {% csrf_token %}
    <title>Просмотр птиц пользователем: {{ login }}</title>
  <div class="abusteku-deagulus">
      {% for bird in view %}
        <div class="item">
            <label></label>
        <img src="/{{ bird.PNG }}" alt="" width="600" height="650">
            <td>Птица: {{ bird.name }} Цвет: {{ bird.feather_color}}</td>
              <td>Дата и время просмотра: {{ bird.DataTime }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

`models.py`:

```py
class Birds(models.Model):
    id_birds = models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    id_user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, unique=True)
    PNG = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    feather_color = models.TextField(max_length=70, null=False)


class ViewedUser(models.Model):
    id_view = models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    id_birds = models.ForeignKey('Birds', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, unique=True)
    id_user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
    DataTime = models.DateTimeField(null=False)


class User(models.Model):
    id_user = models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    login = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, unique=True)
    mail = models.EmailField(null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)


def __str__(self):
    return self.name, self.PNG, self.feather_color, self.id_birds
```

И вот ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пишет нет таких таблиц

Comment: А вы что-нибудь предприняли, чтобы эти таблицы были? Миграции какие-нибудь, например?

Comment: Да, конечно, они существуют

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sql_get = """SELECT Birds.name, Birds.PNG, Birds.feather_color, ViewedUser.DataTime
FROM birdsviews_user AS User, birdsviews_birds AS Birds,
birdsviews_vieweduser AS ViewedUser
WHERE User.login = %s
AND Birds.id_birds = ViewedBirds.id_birds
AND User.id_user = ViewedBirds.id_user
GROUP BY ViewedBirds.DataTime;""" % login

"""
По умолчанию Django выясняет имя таблицы базы данных путем присоединения к “маркировке приложения модели”
– имя, в котором Вы использовали manage.py startapp – к имени класса модели, с подчеркиванием между ними.
"""